# Laravel9: sum child rows for parent based on ID

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have 2 tables: invoices, and coletes. When I create the view page for the invoice I want all the coletes to be numbered in there and their totaleuro summed

basically it should look something like this:

```
invoiceID    coleteID  TotalEuro(Of Colete)  
1             1            100
              2            200
              3            400

                    Total  700    
 
2             4            200
              5            300
              6            500
                   Total  1000
```

My query looks like this

```
 $sum = DB::table('coletes')
    ->join('invoices','coletes.invoice_id','=','invoices.id')
    ->select(DB::raw('
    SUM(coletes.totaleuro) as totaleuro',
    ))
    
    ->get();
```

But instead of returning invoice1 total : 700
invoice2 total: 1000

I just get total: 1700

Anybody has any idea how to solve this query?

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you are considering all the coletes belong to a single invoice.  you need to use group by to get invoice level total

```
 $sum = DB::table('coletes')
->join('invoices','coletes.invoice_id','=','invoices.id')
->select(DB::raw('
SUM(coletes.totaleuro) as totaleuro',
))->groupBy('coletes.invoice_id')
->get();
```

so it will return two rows as per your example

MySQL Query for your example

```
CREATE TABLE coletes (
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 invoice_number INTEGER NOT NULL,
 product_id INTEGER not NULL,
 amount INTEGER not null
);

-- insert
INSERT INTO coletes VALUES (0001, 1,1, 100); 
INSERT INTO coletes VALUES (0002, 1,2, 200);
INSERT INTO coletes VALUES (0003, 1,3, 400);

INSERT INTO coletes VALUES (0004, 2,4, 200);
INSERT INTO coletes VALUES (0005, 2,5, 300);
INSERT INTO coletes VALUES (0006, 2,6, 500);

-- fetch 
SELECT  invoice_number, sum(amount) FROM coletes group by 
invoice_number;
 
Output:

invoice_number  sum(amount)
 1              700
 2              1000
```